# Bounded in expectated absolute value implies bounded in probability ($O_p(1)$)

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, expected-value, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose $X_n$ is a sequence of real value random variable and $E(\|X_n\|)<\infty$. Then $X_n=O_p(1)$.

My thinking is to use Markov inequality.
$$
P(\|X\|\geq a)\leq \frac{E\|X\|}{a}
$$
Now choose $a =  \frac{E\|X\|}{\epsilon}$. Then
$$
(\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists a<\infty)(P(\|X\|<a)>1-\frac{E\|X\|}{E\|X\|/\epsilon}=1-\epsilon 
$$
as required.

Is this correct? Any alternative proof?

Definition:
A sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is said to be $O_p(1)$ if and only if
$$
(\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists K<\infty )(P(\|X_n\|<K)>1-\epsilon\ \  \forall n \in N)
$$

Comment: What is the definition of $O_p$?

Comment: @WilliamM. I think i messed up the formulation. I have corrected it and given the definition of $O_p(1)$.

Comment: The statement is  false.  $X_n=n$ is a counter-example. Did you mean $\sup_n E(\|X_n\|)<\infty$?

Comment: What you are trying to prove is called "tightness" (when the $X_n$ are $\mathbf{R}^d$-valued) and it is a form of compacity for the _distribution_ functions. What you wrote is _obviously false_ because you require a bound in the expectations (as already pointed out by others). What is _true_ is that a sequence of bounded random vectors in $\mathbf{L}_p$ (with values in $\mathbf{R}^d$) has a corresponding sequence of distributions that is _tight._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your assumption the claim is false and $X_n=n$ is a  counter-example. If you assume that $\sup_n E\|X_n\|<\infty$ then you can prove it as follows:

Let $C=\sup_n E\|X_n\|$. Then $P(\|X_n\|\geq M)\leq \frac {E\|X_n\|} M\leq \frac C M <\epsilon$ for $M >\frac C {\epsilon}$. Hence,  $P(\|X_n\|<M)>1-\epsilon$ if $M >\frac C {\epsilon}$.